# Как определить завершилось ли выполнение консольной команды?

Tags: yii2, cron

Есть проект на Yii 2 и несколько консольных команд повешенных на крон. Какая-то запускается раз в минуту, какая-то раз в полчаса. Как узнать выполнилась та или иная команда и если нет то не запускать ее?

Comment: http://bencane.com/2015/09/22/preventing-duplicate-cron-job-executions/

Answer (score 1):

Ии не причем, Вам нужно где-то сохранять время выполнения последней успешной команды, БД\файл\кэш